# css background-image not displaying

Tags: image, google-chrome, background

I have the following code on home page:

```
<ul id="slides1">
<li>
<!-- About-->
<a href="index.html"><div class="logo"></div></a>
<div class="sub1"> </div>
<a href="#" style="display:block;"> <img src="images/nadpisi/about.png" class="nadpis1"></a>
<img id="i1" src="images/MiddleBg/first.jpg"/>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here I have logo in class=logo and div class sub1 has background image in css file:

```
.sub1{
  background-image: url(../images/sub1/about.png);
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 7;
  top: 270px;
  margin-left: 490px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  }
  .logo {
    background-image: url(../images/LOGO.png);
     width: 229px;
     height: 129px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 10;
     top: 80px;
     margin-left: 490px;
     }
```

When I open the page with Chrome, both these logo and sub1 background images are not displayed but image after them does display, but when I go to browser`s address bar and press Enter they display. What is the problem, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your images are probably not being found. Most likly a problem with your paths. Check if the image loads in a developer console.

Comment: image path is correct. If it was not found, how would it appear when I press enter on address bar?

Comment: sorry I thought that was part of the image that was loading. What is the problem if you hit reload they don't load?

Comment: if I click reload button, they don`t load(don`t appear as they were first time). If I select address bar with mouse and press enter they immediately appear.

Comment: do you have a link where I can see this?

Comment: I found the solution. As you can see both logo and sub1 has position:absolute, but I forgot to set their parent which is <li> to position:relative. so, after adding position:relative to css of <li> it works fine